# Custom application doesn't appear in list of windows to share in Microsoft Teams or Skype

Tags: .net, wpf, microsoft-teams, skype, skype-for-business

I have a custom WPF application, .NET 4.5, and for some reason it doesn't show up in the list of windows that can be shared in Microsoft Teams (or in Skype).

My first theory was that it had something to do with the window style, since we have a custom toolbar and some other custom stuff, but messing around with that so far hasn't made it work.

I can share the application by sharing the whole desktop, but I'd like to be able to select just the application for sharing by itself.

Does anyone know how Teams/Skype decides what windows should be shown in the sharing list, or what I might be missing to make my application appear in that list?

Comment: You cannot share the application by sharing whole desktop

Comment: What I mean is that I can share the desktop, and people in the meeting can see whatever windows I have on that desktop, but what I want is for just the individual window to show up in the list of windows I can share.

Comment: Could you please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, finally. I had to set the Title attribute in the Window.xaml file, I was setting it later via code but apparently that wasn't good enough. Having a non-empty title makes the window appear in the list of shareable applications in Teams.